# Record video (and audio) from webcam using vlcj

Tags: java, webcam, record, vlc, vlcj

I am trying to make a java program that will record video and audio from my webcam (or some other stream/source). I am using code from the vlcj tutorial, andwhen I run it in Netbeans I get no error messages but it only records audio if the acodec is mpga, and only video if the acodec is mpga. Here is my code:

```
package cyclops;

/**
 *
 * @author Black Tie
 */
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

public class Cyclops {


    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
        RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),LibVlc.class);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Cyclops();
            }
        });
    }

    private Cyclops() {
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lesson Record");

        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        String mediaURL= "dshow://";
               mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediaURL,":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=16},scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\Black Tie\\Documents\\vlcVideos\\trial13j.mpg");

    }


}
```

If anyone could give me advice on what may be going wrong I would very much appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Your sout string has a missing trailing "}". What happens if you fix that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed the trailing "}", but the same problems occur - I can still only get audio or video.

Comment: Do you mean you get *either* audio or video, but not both?. I'm surprised audio is working at all since you usually have to use an input slave as far as I know, and you don't specify one (maybe dshow does give you the audio, so I may be wrong on that point). Anyway, what happens if you use the VLC application to save the audio and video from your webcam?

Comment: Yes, I can either get audio (with mpga) or video (with mp4a). When I use vlcj to just play the video and audio in a window it all works fine, it's only when I add the line of code to save it to a file that I have issues. Using VLC I'm only able to record audio, although I may be doing something wrong when trying that. Thanks for continuing to help me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You need to get it working in VLC first.